# Convolution of probabilities on finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, convolution

I was reading a book on group and representation theory and came across the following which I don't understand, I'd appreciate any help.

> Suppose P and Q are probabilities on a finite group G. Thus $P(s)\ge0$ and $\sum_s P(s)=1$. By the convolution $P*Q$ we mean the probability $P*Q(s)=\sum_t P(st^{-1})Q(t)$; "first pick $t$ from $Q$, then independently pick $u$ from $P$ and form the product $ut.$" Note that in general $P*Q \ne Q*P$.

***EDIT***: the first line is standard, but the latter I cant figure.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @Hempelicious, I don't understand why P*Q(s) is equal to the sum of P(st^(-1))Q(t). where did the "t" come from

Comment: It's just the definition of convolution. It says "sum over all pairs of elements in $G$ whose product is $s$".